# Something like a joystick in PyQt

Tags: qt, user-interface, pyqt4

This seems like such a common thing I am convinced I am missing something obvious.  I want a widget that gives 2 dimensional information based on something the user drags around.  In my mind this is a joystick, but this [color picker](http://www.rapidtables.com/web/color/RGB_Color.htm) which is very common conveys the same concept.  I could build the widget based on an image and click events, but it seems like there should be a simpler way to cobble this functionality together without so much work.  Any Ideas?

Edit:
It doesn't matter what is being moved.  In the simplest case the user could just click in a square and two sliders (one vertical and one horizontal) could be set based on the click location.

Edit2:
I want to get real time information from the user to control a system, such as speed and direction.  It is much more intuitive and faster for a user to convey this information with a joystick type system.  So far forward yields speed while simultaneously left-right yields direction.  Otherwise the user has to drag left some move to the other slider, drag it up and so forth.  This is why 2-dimensional information is conveyed in game controllers and RC electronics.  I just was looking for a widget that correlates to that.

Comment: what information, dragging around what? Whatever you mean, it will require custom painting I think.

Comment: What specific information are you trying to represent with this widget? If you're going to set two sliders, then why not just allow the user to move the sliders themselves to set the x and y?

Comment: Given your updated description, the proposed widget seems quite specialized - or anyway not a "common thing", as you put it, which explains why it is not part of the generic widget-set provided by Qt. So I suppose you will have to implement your own solution (or look for a third-party one).

Answer (score 1):

Make a `QWidget`.

Set its minimum size.

Implement its mouse events. (And if you are using the new touch event stuff, make sure you handle those, too.)

Then on mouse drag or on a mouse press, adjust your vertical scale based on the y part of the pos of the mouse event and adjust your horizontal scale based on the x part of the pos of the mouse event.

If you want to preview or mark what a click would do before a click or a drag is started, you will want to implement the mouseMove event, and also `enableMouseTracking` for your widget.

Emit the information to the relevant widgets.

Make a paintEvent that represent the information in the way that makes the most sense, either with printed text, changing colors, a circle changing size, etc.

Or if you don't want your input widget to show the change in info but a nearby widget to reflect it, connect to it, and setup it's events to handle it.

It shouldn't take too long to make this kind of an input device.  The hardest part probably is deciding what to do when a click or a drag occurs or finishes.

Also if you are creating a kind of analog joystick, they usually have a dead-zone in the middle.  So you could throw in a check to see if it is close enough to the zero position.

And if you want it to behave like a spring loaded joystick, you could have it begin animating back to its home position, every time you let go of the widget.

Hope that helps.